# Using SCP from a macbook to a Jupyter notebook version of Linux

Tags: linux

I am struggling trying to get a movie file from the desktop of my macbook to a specific file location on this linux instance. I have googled extensively and I think my problem is that I need an IP address of the linux instance but the linux instance is online on my macbook so I'm confused. Attached is a picture of my linux instance here: [linux instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXs2.png). The path to my movie on my mac is : /Users/me/Desktop/testfish.mov. Any help would be appreciated.

If it helps I am trying to do this to implement yolo on a random movie that I found online. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Sorry.. Thank you for the help!